# Symfony2 get service or get container service

Tags: web-services, symfony, service, symfony-2.4

i have just implemented my first *service* in Symfony2.

I noticed that, within a controller method, whether i call the service so

```
$this->container->get('main.service');
```

or so

```
$this->get('main.service');
```

there is no difference.

I get the *service* equally with both.

Where are the differences?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no difference if you're extending the [Base Controller](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php) provided by Symfony.

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class YourController extends Controller
```

If you take a deeper look at the implementation of the [Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php),  you may notice that it provides a `get()` helper which do exactly the same call as what you did first (getting your service through the container).

**So, then,**

There's no difference as `$this->get('something')` simply sencapsulates a call to `$this->container->get('something')`.

---

Here's the implementation of the `get()` method you're calling when doing `$this->get('main.service');`

```
/**
 * Gets a service by id.
 *
 * @param string $id The service id
 *
 * @return object The service
 */
public function get($id)
{
    return $this->container->get($id);
}
```